# FCM credentials for different domain

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using FCM credentails for my domain(abcd.com) and if any user come to site 
and add their domain (xyz.com), so is it necessary to have seperate FCM credentials or user can use the credentials of domain (abcd.com) for sending notification.

Please help me to clarify the concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",`enter code here`
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

here the apiKey keys will unique every project
so no need seperate FCM credentials

Comment: How we will get the <API_KEY> for different project without registering the project, in that case we need to register the domain to get api key?

Comment: @Sikander have you figured this out?